# Generating a random sequence of 6 numbers with Python sometimes yields a result with only 5

Tags: python-3.x, string, random, digits

I have a small problem with a function that should potentially generate a random 6-digit code. The code in itself is absolutely straightforward, using python 3 I do it like this:

```
def secret_code(num=6):
numbers = string.digits
code = ''
for _ in range(num):
    code += random.choice(numbers)

return int(code)
```

Now, there is a gazillion way to do this but I am not questioning the validity of this method, in particular, against others, my issue is that sometimes this function returns a 5-digit code.

I have tried a for loop with 1000 cycles to test how often this happens, in this way:

```
for _ in range(1000):
    code = secret_code() # calling the function above
    if len(code) < 6:
        count += 1

ratio = count/1000
print(ratio*100) # at this point the test has given back 0% all the times
```

and it always comes back 0% of the time.

However, when applied to a website, for example, I am using it to generate random verification codes to send to new users, sometimes (I don't mean 50% of the times, of course, but it's not even 0) it comes out with 5 digits instead of 6 and, for the life of me, I can't figure out why.

Does somebody have any idea why this occurs? and more importantly, why doesn't it show up in the "for loop test"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matter is that `string.digits` contains `0`, so your variable `code` in function may contain something like `0123`, therefore `int('0123')` returns `123`.
And secondly, python says, that "`object of type 'int' has no len()`", so you may use `len(str(code))` in your *if* statement.

Comment: Oh my goood! thanks, you are absolutely right. That was silly of me but man it really was driving me insane